# Custom ArrayAdapter, super can't be resolved

Tags: java, android, android-arrayadapter

```
public class ImageAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ImageView> {
    Context context;
    String[] PosterList;

    public ImageView(Context context, String[] PosterList){
        super(context, 0, PosterList);
        this.context = context;
        this.PosterList = PosterList;
    }
}
```

So in the code snippet above, is the constructor for a custom ArrayAdapter. The "super" method can not be resolved. I'm not sure why, considering that the method signature written above matches one of the constructors on the android website for ArrayAdapter. How can I fix this?

Since I'm using Picasso to download images into a gridview, I'm copying a array of strings (that are actually URLs) so they can be processed by Picasso in the getView method and return an ImageView object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change

```
 public class ImageAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ImageView>
 ...
     public ImageView(Context context, String[] PosterList)
```

to (respectively)

```
 public class ImageAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>
 ...
     public ImageAdapter(Context context, String[] PosterList)
```

You are defining the wrong **constructor**.

Comment: Also, change `ArrayAdapter<ImageView>` to `ArrayAdapter<String>`.

Comment: Also, the OP can  get rid of the field assignment `String[] PosterList` as this assignment is already done via the super class, see the code here at https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.java#68  and all usages of `mObjects` it contains

Comment: @petey but I thought that was one of those good programming habits, isn't it ? (I mean this way he could keep track of the elements of the ListView)

Comment: ArrayAdapter already does that and more, see the all the extra goodies contained in ArrayAdapter's public methods like (add, addall, clear, remove, etc) here http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#pubmethods

Comment: @petey Thanks for the extra tips !

Comment: I can't believe that I put in the wrong name for the constructor and didn't even realize it. Thanks for the help!